# Jar file not working in target folder but working in project folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

When I run the project in STS, it's working fine. All the pages in the webapp folder are loading in the browser. But when I build the project and run the JAR file (**folder:** D:\SpringBoot Projects\DemoExample\target) and go to the page URL, I'm getting Whitelabel error.
In another project I used spring security- In that project the login page is loading fine, but all the JSP pages in the webapp folder are not loading just like the above example.
While trying to solve this problem, I moved the JAR file from target folder to project folder (D:\SpringBoot Projects\DemoExample) and again ran the JAR file, now the JSP pages are loading fine. The JSP pages are only loading in that folder, if I moved the file to another folder, the pages are not loading.
I want to make sure that I can run the JAR file from any folder.

**POM File:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoExample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DemoExample</name>
    <description>Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.37</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    

    <build>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>${basedir}/${target.dir}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Main Class:**

```
    package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoExampleApplication.class, args);      
    }

}
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
}
```

**JSP File:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello
</body>
</html>
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVYQI.jpg)

[Running Jar file in target folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08nwk.jpg)

[Result after running Jar file in target folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv6c9.jpg)

[Running Jar in project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGfY1.jpg)

[Result after running Jar file in project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdUdh.jpg)

Comment: Put you jsp files under webapp/WEB-INF directory. I guess it should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried that and updated the application.properties :( prefix= /WEB-INF/),also tried (/WEB-INF/view) . I'm still facing the same problem, it's working when I run the project in STS, but when I convert it to JAR, then the JSP page is not found

Comment: JSP only works with WAR this is also stated in the Spring Boot documentation and is limited in what you can do. I would strongly suggest using something like Thymeleaf or Mustache in favour of JSPs.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first project using Maven & Springboot, so I don't know about that. I'll learn how to work with Thymeleaf and implement the project again